# How do I mock functions in Mocha and Sinon with functions within a function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js, sinon, chai

So for starters, I'm using `coffeescript`, but I'll add the JS code as well. I tried a bunch of different things but for the most part, everything ends up with `Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function` or something similar. In the case of a fake server, I got back 0 results when I expected, say 20.

```
// As JS
downloadResults = (function(_this) {
    return function(q) {
        var conn;
        conn = new s.AjaxRequest(queryString);
        conn.success = function(data) {
            return downloadResultsSuccess(data, q);
        };
        conn.error = function(data) {
            return downloadResultsError(data, q);
        };
        conn.post();
        return true;
    };
})(this);

# As coffee
downloadResults = (q) =>
    conn = new s.AjaxRequest queryString
    conn.success = (data) => downloadResultsSuccess data, q
    conn.error = (data) => downloadResultsError data, q
    conn.post()
    true
```

OK, so what do I want to test? Well for starters, I want to mock the `s.AjaxRequest` bit so that when `conn.post()` is called, success is returned with the fake `data`. Next, I want to make sure that the function `downloadResultsSuccess` is called if success else `downloadResultsError` is called. And finally ideally, I want to make validate what data has.

Here are some things I've tried:

```
sinon.stub(s.AjaxRequest, 'post').yieldsTo('success', fakeData)

sinon.stub(s.AjaxRequest,'post')
    .withArgs('/fake/server/data.json')
    .returns({
        post: function() {
            return $.promise().done(fakeData);
        }
    });

server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith('POST', '/fake/server/data.json', [
    200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, fakeData
]);
```

Any other ideas on what I should do next?

Comment: Why mock this? Why not just use the fake server to return the data and then try the different scenarios instead? There is little use in mocking/spying on this since you can test it by actually using the code. Make the fake server respond with status 200 in one test, testing the good route and make it respond with 400 in another, testing the bad route. You can regard the Ajax calls as an implementation detail then.

Comment: @limelights So that is how I started off, and I just want to test to see if `downloadResultsSuccess` is called once with the correct data set. There are other variables within the class that determine what type of data needs to be returned, and eventually I'll get to testing that as well. But for now, keeping in mind that `downloadResults` isn't a `promise`, how exactly would I test what the response was? After the `server.respondWith` seen above, I have `className.downloadResults(q)` in my test...where do I go from there?

Comment: The success handler must return something right? So using mocha you'd call the `done()` callback and then assert on your returned value.